# Excel Macros - Removing leading space before an equal sign

Tags: excel, vba

Updated question:

I want to remove the leading space in a cell before an equal sign to activate the formula the cell consists of.

The code for removing the leading space I am using only works for cells formatted as text, so I have created a macro that turns the cell into text, removes the leading space and then converts the cell format into number.

```
Sub RemoveSpaces()

    Selection.NumberFormat = "@"

    ActiveCell.Formula = LTrim(ActiveCell.Formula)

    Selection.NumberFormat = "0.00"
End Sub
```

The problem I am facing is that the formula does not get activated after running the macro. I have to enter the cell and then press enter for the formula to get activated, the issue I then get is that the macro always gives me the same answer, even when the formula is different. Below you can see the code I used for that macro.

```
Sub RemoveSpaces()

    Selection.NumberFormat = "@"

    ActiveCell.Formula = LTrim(ActiveCell.Formula)

    Selection.NumberFormat = "0.00"

    Range("C33").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "= 224.02*EXP(-0.013*R[-29]C)-R[-31]C[-1]"
End Sub
```

So, does anyone know how I can solve this problem?

Comment: Wouldn't you want to replace `_=` with `=`? (Underscore represents a space) and not every space in a cell?

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs Thanks for the input but I have unfortunately already tried that and it gave me the exact same outcome as the code that was stated in the question did.

Comment: Why not use TRIM?

Comment: if you could give print screen of your cells together with how the cells are formatted ("General" or "Text") perhaps we could help further.

Comment: You say _I have created a macro that turns the cell into text_, what was in the cell before turning it into text?

Comment: The cell was in the general format.

Comment: Ok, general format, but what was in the cell?

Comment: An equation from a trendline that is regularly being updated. In the example I wrote in the question, the cell consisted of:   =224.02*EXP(-0.013*R[-29]C)-R[-31]C[-1]. And the formula is valid, after I enter the cell and press enter the formula gets activated and calculates a number. But the issue I get when I enter the cell and press enter, as stated in the question,  is that the macro always gives me the same answer, even when the formula is different.

Comment: Note that Selection and ActiveCell are not the same. Selecting a cell does not make it the ActiveCell.

Answer (score 0):

This will remove all leading spaces from the active cell, and set the text as the formula of the active cell.

The code is to be put behind the sheet of the active cell, and a cell must be selected.

```
Sub RemoveSpaces()
   ActiveCell.Formula = LTrim(ActiveCell.Value)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but when I run your code I get an error message (Run-time error '1004':  Application-defined or object-defined error). When I press debug, it is the second row (ActiveCell.Value = LTrim(ActiveCell.Value)) that is highlighted in yellow.

Comment: @Empan - Updated answer.

Comment: When the cell is formatted as text, the leading space gets removed with your code but the issue is that I want the cell to turn into a formula, thus the equal sign but when the cell is formatted as text, the cell does not turn into a formula. When I have the cell formatted as general or number I receive the error message I  mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: @Empan - Ah, this is a different question! I updated my answer. Note that if the text of the formula is wrong, the macro will fail.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I'm still experiencing the same difficulties. The leading space gets removed when the cell is formatted as text but when the cell is formatted as text or general, I receive the error message.

Comment: @Empan - Is the text after the leading space a valid formula?

Comment: I have now updated the question with more details. Let me know if you need further details. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

If you have no instances of " =" in the middle of a cell and only a single space before the equal sign, then this:

```
Sub Kleanup()
    Cells.Replace What:=" =", Replacement:="="
End Sub
```

will remove the leading space and convert the text to a formula.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I get the same outcome as with the code I used. When I run the Macro, nothing happens. No error message or so but the leading space before the equal sign remains and the cell is not converted into a formula.